# Do variables/flags can be affected by another thread on a non-synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example I have a non-synchronized method like this:

```
public void nonSynchronized(){
     boolean flag = false;

     if(/*some condition*/){
          flag = true;
     }

     //more line of codes here


     if(flag == true){ 
          //do something here - let's say line 33.
     }

}
```

What if a first **thread** executes the method then sets the `flag` to `true`, and before executing the line 33 another **thread** executes the method then resets the variable `flag` to `false`, Will the first **thread** still execute line 33?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `flag` is a local variable. Each thread gets its own copy on the stack. They don't interfere with each-other at all. That can only happen with shared state, i.e. things on the heap, i.e. fields of the object.

Comment: Hi, can I have a follow up question? how about the parameters? do threads have its own copy to? thanks.

Comment: Yes, parameters are essentially local variables, too, and they also live on the stack. Of course, if the parameters are objects, the data inside that object is on the shared heap.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. its(boolean flag) is a local variable. Local variable are not on shared memory. they 
are local/private to thread stack and hence not effected other threads/processor.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a thread it will have its own stack. Each thread will have its own stack and one thread never shares its stack with other thread. All local variables defined in your program will be allocated memory in stack. Hence the answer is **Yes** your `flag` variable will be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is thread safe as it is not working on any shared resource such as a static variable. Your flag is a method variable, and each thread will have a local copy of it.